# Cs50 pset5 speller segmentation, memory errors

Tags: c, cs50

I'm doing the speller program and for the past few days I feel like I'm going in circles, receiving the same problems over and over again. Now, the error is free(): "invalid pointer
Aborted", most likely refering to the hash function, in which I use calloc,yet I can't understand what am I doing wrong there. Most likely there are multiple mistakes in my other functions, so tips regarding them would be very appreciated. I'll post the entire program, so I don't have to send snippets of it later. Completely lost here.
**Ok, thanks to Tim Randal's answer the free() error looks fixed, however a segmentation error mentioned previously took his place.**

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "dictionary.h"
#include <strings.h>
#include <ctype.h>
// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
char word[LENGTH + 1];
struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 1000;

// Number of words loaded into the dictionary
int counter = 0;
// Hash table
node *table[N] = {0};

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
size_t len = strlen(word);
char *lower = calloc(len+1, sizeof(char));

for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    lower[i] = tolower((unsigned char)word[i]);
}
node *cursor = NULL;
cursor = table[hash(lower)];
while (cursor != NULL)
{
    if (strcasecmp(cursor->word,lower) == 0)
    {
        free(lower);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        cursor = cursor->next;
    }
}
free(lower);
return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
//hash function djb2 by Dan Bernstein
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    size_t len = strlen(word);
char *lower = calloc(len+1, sizeof(char));

for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) 
{
    lower[i] = tolower((unsigned char)word[i]);
}
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    int c;

    while ((c = *lower++))
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */
    free(lower);
    if (hash > N)
    {
        hash = hash % N;
        return hash;
    }
    else
    {   
        return hash;
    }

 }

 // Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
 bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
char word[LENGTH + 1];
node *new_node = NULL;
node *tmp = NULL;
FILE *file = fopen(dictionary,"r");
if (file == NULL)
{
    printf("Could not open file\n");
    return false;
}
while(fscanf(file, "%s",word) != EOF)
{
    new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (new_node == NULL)
    {
        printf("Not enough memory!\n");
        return false;
    }
    strcpy(new_node->word,word);
    unsigned int index = hash(word);
    
    if(table[index] == NULL)
    {
        table[index] = new_node;  
        new_node->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
    tmp = table[index];
    table[index] = new_node;
    new_node->next = tmp;
    }
    counter++;
    


}
return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{

return counter;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
const char *word = NULL;
int index = hash(word);
for(node *cursor = table[index]; cursor != NULL;cursor = cursor->next)
{
    for(node *tmp = table[index]; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->next)
    {
        free(tmp);
    }
    free(cursor);
}   
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one problem. I'm not saying it's the only one.

```
while ((c = *lower++))
    hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */
free(lower);
```

You're freeing a pointer after changing it. You will need to copy `lower` to another pointer, which gets incremented and tested. The original `lower` needs to remember the address of the first byte allocated.

```
char* test = lower;
while ((c = *test++))
    hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */
free(lower);
```